# Java API to read Azure EventHub Partition list using EventProcessorClient client (Latest SDK)

Tags: azure-eventhub, java

I need to get the List of Partitions for an EventHub. I am trying to use EventProcessorClient from the Latest SDK. This does not seem to have a getRuntimeInformation method.

Is there any way I can get the list of partitions foa an EventHub using any API for a EventProcessorClient client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor is intended to manage partitions on your behalf and without any explicit action on your part, so it does not expose any means to inspect the Event Hub or its properties.

To inspect your Event Hub and its partitions, you'll want to use the `EventHubClientBuilder` to create either a producer or consumer client to do so.  I'd recommend taking a peek at [GetEventHubMetadata.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/GetEventHubMetadata.java) from the client library samples, which demonstrates doing so.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use EventProcessorClient as it give me all the functionality I needed except a list of Partitions. I need the List of Partitions so that I can determine the last processed offset of each partition for a consumer. This is a custom requirement.